# .Type does not have a member - Error in Swift

Tags: ios7, swift, xcode6

```
import UIKit

class Service: NSObject {       
        let urlValue:NSURL = NSURL(string: "www.google.com")!
        let request:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL:urlValue)
}
```

I am getting the error "Service.Type does not have member named urlValue".

But,

```
let request:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL:NSURL(string: "www.google.com")!)
```

Works fine!. I am confused, where I went wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Type does not have a member](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582853/type-does-not-have-a-member)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [Change the X and Y in a CGRectMake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/change-the-x-and-y-in-a-cgrectmake) (with a different solution).