# Array inside of array in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, uitableview, swift

Let's say I have 3 array's and I want to display them in an `UITableView`. The array is composed of `NSString`s. But the array's are not of all the same length. What is the best way to get them in the `UITableView`, with sections for each array? I thought you could put many arrays inside of an array to help with this? Please provide a detailed answer for a noob. :)

```
let name = ["Name", "Address","Phone", "DOB"]
let work = ["Name", "Address","Main Phone", "Manager Name", "Manager Phone"]
let property = ["Address","State", "Zip"]

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 3

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let object = name[indexPath.row] as String
            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController).topViewController as DetailViewController
            controller.detailItem = object
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if (section == 0) {
        return name.count
    }else if (section == 1) {
        return work.count
    }else if (section == 2) {
        return property.count;
    }else{
        return 1
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {


    if(section == 0){
        title = "Personal Info"
    }else if (section == 1){
        title = "Work Info"
    }else if (section == 2){
        title = "Property"
    }

    return title
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let NameInfo = name[indexPath.row]
    let WorkInfo = work[indexPath.row]
    let rentalInfo = property[indexPath.row]


    if (indexPath.section == 0){
        cell.textLabel!.text = NameInfo
    }else if (indexPath.section == 1){
        cell.textLabel!.text = WorkInfo
    }else if (indexPath.section == 2){
        cell.textLabel!.text = rentalInfo
    }

    return cell
}
```

If each array is not the same length, I get this error: **fatal error:Array index out of range.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the intermediate variables (NameInfo, WorkInfo, rentalInfo).  Since you're assigning to those regardless of which section the current request is for, one or more will be a bad reference for arrays with uneven lengths.

By choosing the array according to the section (`cell.textLabel!.text = name[indexPath.row]`), you won't be extracting data on an array/section mismatch.

Or, if you're going to be reusing the logic, you could create a function to do it.

Instance variable inside the controller class:

```
var myArrays: [[String]] = []
```

Initialization inside `awakeFromNib`:

```
    myArrays.append(name)
    myArrays.append(work)
    myArrays.append(property)
```

The function:

```
func textForIndexPath(path:NSIndexPath) -> String {
    var result = "Bad path"

    if path.section >= 0 && path.section < myArrays.count {
        let theArray = myArrays[path.section]
        if path.row >= 0 && path.row < theArray.count {
            result = theArray[path.row]
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: That answers my main question, thank you! On the detail view however, I have 1 textfield I'm using to allow users to edit the cells. I want the selected row (Cell) to show in this textfield and allow to edit it. how would I do this with 3 arrays? I added the code above.

Comment: Create a function that takes an index path as input and returns a string.  It should work by using the section to select an array and the row to select the position inside the array.  You can then use that function both to get text for your cell and the equivalent text during the segue.

Comment: Thank you Phillip, would you mind an example please?

Comment: `let myArrays = [name, work, property]` gives an error that MasterViewController does not have a member named _name_. I ran into this before...

Comment: I'm just going by your line `let name = ["Name", "Address","Phone", "DOB"]`.  If that's not correct or not in scope, you'll have to tell me.  (The code worked fine inside a playground after I copied your 3 array definitions.)

Comment: Yes thats correct, it does work inside playground! But, if you put that inside a MasterViewController, it throws that error.

Comment: I wonder if it's a collision with some other variable.  What if you change "name" in both places to something that's likely to be unique?

Comment: I've done that too. Also tried taking it completely out and only having work and property in there, then the next one in line gets the same error. (work) Thats why I was original asking about the array inside of an array, to cut down on the else if statements like this [here](http://briterideas.blogspot.com/2012/07/uitableview-how-to-part-3-multiple.html)

Comment: OK, I'm updating the answer, though I'll have to figure out **why** it fails some other time.

Comment: I really do appreciate your help!

Comment: And the reason my playground code didn't work inside a class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582853/type-does-not-have-a-member

Comment: So all the arrays need to go inside an `init` or `struct`?

Comment: Not so sure about `struct` but it seems that instance variables that rely on other instance variables need to be constructed at run-time.