# Referencing self in notification block in swift

Tags: swift, notifications, block

Because I'm sick of misspelling a selector name I figured I'd try to do some notification stuff with blocks instead of selectors.

I've put together some sample code that doesn't seem to work because I'm unable to access self

```
var currentString : String?

// Type alias the notificaitonBlock
typealias notificationBlock = (NSNotification?) -> ()

// in this case note is an NSNotification?
let strNotification : notificationBlock = { notification in
    if let msg = notification?.object as? String {
        self.currentString = msg
    }
}
```

Assuming this code worked I would register it with:

```
nc.addObserverForName(UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, 
    object: self, 
    queue: NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(), 
    usingBlock: strNotification)
```

Xcode is giving me the following error:

**NotificationTests.swift:49:4: 'NotificationTests -> () -> NotificationTests' does not have a member named 'currentString'**

which implies self isn't pointing to the class but the block or something?

Comment: are you declaring the notificationblock as an instance variable?

Comment: I assume that it is the same issue as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582853/type-does-not-have-a-member, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855137/viewcontrol-type-does-not-have-a-member-named and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/how-to-initialize-properties-that-depend-on-each-other/25856755#25856755: The initialization of one property cannot depend on the value of another property in the same class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use this when using an instance variable for the block:

```
lazy var block: (NSNotification?) -> () = { notification in
    if let msg = notification?.object as? String {
        self.currentString = msg
    }
}
```

or inside a method call:

```
func registerObeserver() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: self, queue: NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(), { notification in
        if let msg = notification?.object as? String {
            self.currentString = msg
        }
    })
}
```

As Martin R mentioned in the comments this probably has to do with one property of a class depending on another during initialization

Unlike this in javascript, self is not changing inside a closure