# I cannot access a function in a custom class; no matter what I try it comes up with errors

Tags: swift

```
import Cocoa

public class Ut {
    public func foo(m: Int) -> Int {
        return m*m
    }
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    let j = 3
    let k = Ut.foo(j) // 'ViewController.Type' does not have a member named 'j'

...
```

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582853/type-does-not-have-a-member, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/how-to-initialize-properties-that-depend-on-each-other, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855137/viewcontrol-type-does-not-have-a-member-named.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can’t access other properties when giving properties their initial values:

```
struct S {
    let a = 1
    // error: S.Type does not have a member named a
    let b = a + 1
}
```

Instead, you have to initialize these values inside `init`:

```
struct S {
    let a: Int
    let b: Int

    init() {
        // note, a must be initialized in here
        // too if b relies on it
        a = 1
        b = a + 1
    }
}
```

(also, it looks like you’re using `Ut.foo` as a class-level function but it’s a member function - but this particular error is about the property init)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your `foo(m: Int)` as class function in order to call directly like that. Otherwise, you have to create an instance of Ut then call foo() on to this instance

```
class func foo(m: Int) -> Int {
        return m*m
}
```

then in other place:
    let k = Ut.foo(j)

**If you pass j as parameter, this call must be placed inside a function, not at class level. If you want to call at class level, pass a value** (like: `let k = Ut.foo(5)` )

Comment: Thanks much.  In hindsight, I see the question was pretty ignorant because you have to instantiate a class, or somehow make it static, before using it.