# Trouble with arrays and randomizing

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift

I have

```
var rockNamesArray:[String] = ["bird", "rock2", "rock3"]

var rockpos = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(3)))

var firstrockString:String = self.rockNamesArray[rockpos]
```

But its telling me that `rockNamesArray` isnt a member. Help?

Comment: Are you using Playgrounds?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855137/viewcontrol-type-does-not-have-a-member-named or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582853/type-does-not-have-a-member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works perfectly in a playground.

```
import Foundation

var rockNamesArray:[String] = ["bird", "rock2", "rock3"]

var rockpos = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(3)))

var firstrockString:String = rockNamesArray[rockpos]
```

it's not clear from your code if those variables are being declared inside a function or at the class level. The issue is the **self.** which refers to member variables so I assume the declaration is inside a function etc.

As ABakerSmith hinted - it's really easy to get to the bottom of these kinds of issues by copying & pasting the offending code into a playground.