# Stored properties in Swift can't refer to each other?

Tags: swift, swift2

What is the reason I can't give a value to a `stored property` that depends on the value of another one in Swift 2.0?

The code below gives an error saying:

> Something.Type does not have a member named 'foo'

```
class Something {
    let foo = "bar"
    let baz = "\(foo) baz"
}
```

This is odd, as `Something.Type` certainly does have a member called foo.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25854300/how-to-initialize-properties-that-depend-on-each-other, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855137/viewcontroller-type-does-not-have-a-member-named, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582853/type-does-not-have-a-member.

Comment: the 'reason' is that the instance has not been initialized yet, and so you cannot refer to its members - see @MartinR's comment for a handful of ways to address this constraint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to initialise the variable `baz`, before swift has had a chance to know that `foo` is a property of `Something`. Place your initialisation inside the `init` constructor.

```
class Something {
    let foo: String
    let baz: String

    init () {
        foo = "bar"
        baz = "\(foo) baz"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `lazy` initialization but now you have to make it a variable:

```
class Something {
    let foo = "bar"
    lazy var baz = { "\(self.foo) baz" }()
}
```